# Showing that $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{6}]$ and $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{7}]$ are PID's using number theory

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-number-theory

I have to show that the class number of $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{6})$ and $L=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{7})$ is 1, i.e. that the ring of integers of $K$ and $L$ ($\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{6}]$ and $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{7}]$ respectively) are PIDs. I've never done such an exercise and I'm having some troubles.

In *Algebraic Theory of Numbers*, by Pierre Samuel, I've found the following tips:

1. first notice, using the Minkowski's bound, that every ideal class (of $K$ and $L$) contains an integral ideal of norm 1 or 2.
2. Show that both $K$ and $L$ contain a principal ideal of norm $2$ if and only if there exist $a,b \in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $a^2-6b^2 =2$ or $-2$.
3. Deduce that the ring of integers of $K$ and the ring of integers of $L$ are PIDs.

The first part is simple as the Minkowski's bound is $<3$.

About the second part: I can compute the norm of an integral element that is of the form $x=a+b\sqrt{6}$. The norm of the principal ideal generated by $x$ is the absolute value of the norm of the element, so I can conclude.

But now how can I deduce 3)?

I know that there are similar questions, but I'd like to solve it the way this book suggests, as I've been studying on this book!
Thank you

Comment: You have a good taste in books, congratulations!

Comment: @MichaëlLeBarbier why?

Comment: @ParclyTaxel Because it is one of my favourite math books at this level, short in length but not in its other qualities. Its terseness supports its crisp clarity, it showcases the diversity of methods used in number theory while being accurate and compact, two aspects that could seem mutually exclusive. The selection of topics is ambitious if not bold. It's even occasionally funny. So refreshing and tasteful. Stewarts Galois Theory or De Bruijn Asymptotic methods have a similar flair but are not as diverse, I believe. They just come next in my ideal math library.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that a prime ideal $P$ has norm a power of a prime $p$ if and only if $P$ is lying above $p$ (that is appears in the decomposition of $pO_K$)

[**Quick proof.** If $O_k/P$ has order $p^m$, then $p^mO_K=(pO_K)^m \subset P$, so $p^m\in P$. Since $P$ is a prime ideal$ ,p\in P$, meaning that $P$ divides $pO_K$ by the rule "containing is dividing".
The converse is clear by taking norms.]

Now since your extension is Galois, the Galois group acts transitively on the set of prime ideals lying above a fixed prime $p$. In particular, if ONE prime ideal lying above $p$ is principal, ALL of them are.

It follows from your work that all prime ideals of norm $2$ are principal. Now, since any ideal class is represented by an ideal of norm $1$ or $2$, it follows that every ideal class is trivial, hence your field is a PID.

Comment: Thank you very much, that really helps me!